# Div/button LOOKS wider than it should be by 1 pixel

Tags: html, debugging, sass, pixel

As you can see on the image below, the dropdown div is a pixel wider than it should have been. The strangest thing is that on **hover** it only changes its color (line 22 of SCSS fiddle) **and it's wider no more!**
Apparently, its width is equal to its parent, but as you can see, it's not.
Maybe it's tied with button hover somehow?

Could somebody explain me the thing with this situation?

[image]

[image]

[image]

The code is like this.
https://jsfiddle.net/can528p2/12/

```
<div class="home">
    <div class="submit">
      <button class="btn-search">
        Search Items
      </button>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul role="menu">
          <li>
            <button>
              Items1
            </button>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button>
              Items2
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>     
      </div>  <!-- /.menu -->   
    </div> <!-- /.submit -->
</div> <!-- /.home -->
```

**SCSS**

```
.home {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  button {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .submit { 
    width: 20%; 
    position: relative;
    .btn-search { 
      background: #ff530d;
      color: #fff;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      &:hover,
      &:focus,
      &:active {
        background-color: #f26202;
        outline: none;
      }
    } //.btn-search
    .menu {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 0;
      ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        button {
          background: #fff;
          border: none;
          outline: none;
          &:hover,
          &:focus,
          &:active {
            background: #ff530d;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
          }
        }
      } 
    } //.menu
  } //.submit
}
```

Comment: That looks like an optical effect to me. Has developer tools confirmed it *IS* actually wider?

Comment: It's the same size for me (Firefox)

Comment: I've tried it a few minutes ago on Firefox and it actually LOOKS wider. 
But all the dev tools say it's the same width.

Comment: Please check the new added image.

Comment: Changing the initial background-color of list buttons to #ff530d fixes the "problem". But why does it appear in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an optical illusion. It's tricking your brain because the dividing edges of the pixels on your monitor are dark and your brain contrasts them with a dark background.  Try changing the whole background color to be a lighter shade and the effect diminishes:

[image]

```
.home {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.7); <--
  button {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/can528p2/13/

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you!